# Windows 7 will not boot up unless connected to External Hard Drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup, boot

When i disconnected my Buffalo Hard Drive my computer starts to boot up and then stops before it auto detects my Hard Drive and Cd/Dvd Rom.

Once i have connected my External Buffalo Hard Drive it starts to boot up ok.

This problem occurs in Windows Xp and i have jsut installed Windows 7 and i am still getting this problem.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Check the device boot order in BIOS, make sure your internal HDD is higher in the list than any external devices. You may have to plug in the Buffalo HDD to get it to appear. This won't explain why it hangs but it may get around the problem until you find a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Could you have accidentally installed the OS on the external HDD? I am not trying to be mean, but it could be an easy mistake to make if you installed the OS on an external HDD. If you did that the OS installed on the external HDD, it would cause this issue. Also, check the device boot order in BIOS as @Tog said.